# What are the limitations of calculated fields in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Unless you're doing something like 'calcfield = field1 - field 2' is seems to complain like anything

Is there a known list of limitations as to what is achievable?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't run into any such limitations. They are limited in the same way that all the VB in SSRS is, but I just created a test calculated field in an SSRS dataset: (SSRS 2008R2)

```
=IIF(Fields!Score.Value > 50, 100, SQRT(Fields!Score.Value))
```

No problems.

But I generally avoid calculated fields: they sometimes get lost when making changes to a dataset, and SSRS decides to refresh the available field list.

What specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: None of the aggregation functions for a start

Comment: Yes, the fields are loaded and calculated as the rows are retrieved, so aggregates don't make sense at that point. Otherwise you could have loops like fieldA `=MAX(Fields!FieldB.Value, "MyDataSet")` and fieldB `=MAX(Fields!FieldA.Value, "MyDataSet")`  What should that return?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by some of your comments I don't think you want calculated fields. I think you want to make a group variable. In the group properties (Create a group that groups on '1' if you want the whole dataset in the group) add a variable with the aggregate expression that you want. You can then refer to that variable anywhere within that group (however BIDS will usually highlight the variable as invalid but ignore the warning). The syntax for referring to a group variable is `Variables!variable_name.Value`